# How to render the correct field name for a 'fake' simple_form_for field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I used a [fake input field](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Create-a-fake-input-that-does-NOT-read-attributes) to get simple_form to render a field that doesn't correspond to a field in the model.

```
class FakeInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  def input(wrapper_options = nil)
    merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options)
    template.text_field_tag(attribute_name, nil, merged_input_options)
  end
end
```

In my form, the model I am working with is deeply nested. This means the input name is long and very specific. An `Event` `has_many` `Positions` which `has_many` `Responsibilities`. I want to add a fake field to the responsibilities called `position_count`.

As you can see in the markup below, the label gets the correct value for its `for` attribute but the input **does not** get the correct `name` attribute. What do I need to change (possibly in the `fake_input.rb` class?) to get the input to have the correct name?

The correct name for the input should be

```
event_positions_attributes_0_responsibilities_attributes_0_position_count
```

but the fake field is only rendered as

```
position_count
```

The markup being rendered is...

```
<div class="input fake optional event_positions_responsibilities_position_count">
    <label for="event_positions_attributes_0_responsibilities_attributes_0_position_count" class="fake optional control-label">Position count</label>
    <input type="text" name="position_count" id="position_count" class="fake optional">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered overriding name attribute `input_html: { name: 'event_positions_attributes_0_responsibilities_attributes_0_position_count' }`

Comment: Any specific reason that you don't just use a virtual attribute in the model instead?

Comment: @max No specific reason. This method is what was recommended in the simple_form wiki.

Comment: I would try that first - just add `attr_accessor :position_count` to `Responsibility` and you can just create an inputs as if it was a regular database column backed attribute.

Comment: Based on other SO questions, it seems like property getters/setters is the preferred way to handle virtual attributes in Rails 4. Immediate tests look promising as the name attribute is properly constructed. I'm still working on wiring up the controller

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are using [`text_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag) - this is one of the "low-level" form helpers that is not bound to an object.

So when you call `template.text_field_tag(attribute_name, nil, merged_input_options)` it actually uses `attribute_name` for the name attribute.

This differs from `SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput` that uses `@builder.text_field(attribute_name, merged_input_options)` which is bound to an object.

#### An easier way

A far simpler way to create an input that does not correspond to a database column is by using "virtual attributes" - in other words just a plain old instance variable with a getter and setter.

```
class Responsibility < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  attr_accessor :position_count
end
```

---

```
<%= simple_form_for(@responsibity) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :position_count %>
<% end %>
```

> By default, Simple Form will look at the column type in the database
>   and use an appropriate input for the column.

Thats not possible in the case - I do believe it will fall back to `:string` (`<input type="text>")` - you can use the `as` option if you want [a specific type](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type) of input.